# Edit Textbox Value in Form MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a search form bound to a field in one of my tables in my database. The textbox in this search form displays a value from the bound field from the table instead of letting me to input a value to search. The locked property is set to No and the enabled property is set to Yes. How do I make the textbox editable so I can search for records

For more context, I have another form in the database used to input records and display the records the search form returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a form has bound controls (controls with a setting to a column), then if the form has no data source, then in most cases, the controls become disabled.

Since this is a search/filter form, then the form should NOT have a data source. That means the form does not need to be bound to some table in the database.

The term for such forms is "an un-bound" form. While the search form can have text boxes, combo box boxes (that have a data source), both the controls and the form does not require a data source.

So, make the form un-bound. That is check if the form has a data source and remove as such.

So, select the form (not a control) and look at the property sheet.

e.g. this:

[image]

And in addition to the above, each of the controls on the form should not have a data source, since each control is not for editing of data. So, check the text box, and make sure it is un-bound (does not have a data source setting).

Note how the designer shows my filter options as "un-bound"

[image]

And if we bring up a property sheet for a given control, then once again, the control will be un-bound (no data column to the forms data source, of which we don't have). So, the control source of that control needs to be blank.

Hence this:

[image]

So, since the form has no data source - it is a user filter form, then make sure the form is un-bound, and also make sure the controls in question are also un-bound.